# FYI: new biblical archaeology magazine

Tags: discussion, research

For those interested in biblical archaeology, a new magazine has recently been published:
[Let The Stones Speak](https://armstrongmazar.com/magazine_issues/1), with potentially interesting topics.

E.g. this first issue includes [Top 10 Biblical Archaeology Discoveries of 2021](https://armstrongmazar.com/637-top-10-biblical-archaeology-discoveries-of-2021)

---

Note that the publication does have backing from a religious organization, but it isn't preachy, and doesn't solicit donations.
In fact, the print version is available totally free of charge.
Other than as a subscriber, I have no personal relationship with the organization.